# Windows Phone 7 - TextBlock Font style is changing when i give into the button content

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I want to add the TextBlock into the Button content. But if i add the TextBlock into the button content the TextBlock font style is changing.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <TextBlock Text="Vijaya dhas" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Black"/>
     <TextBlock Text="Mobile App Developer Trainee" FontSize="26" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
     <TextBlock Text="Chennai" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Medium"/>
</StackPanel>
```

If i give like this my out put is:

[image: OutPut]

If I give this into the button content:

```
<Button Height="200">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Vijaya dhas" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Black"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Mobile App Developer Trainee" FontSize="26" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Chennai" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
```

the out put is:

[image: Out Put 2]

I don't want change the TextBlock font style. Please give any idea to keep the font style what ever it is.

Here i have attached my list box example for your review:

Without Using Button:

[image: With out using Button]

Using Button Content:

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="List Example" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Example" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,0,2,0" Background="#FFE5E5E5">

            <TextBlock Text="List Box With Button Content" Margin="0,150,0,0" FontSize="26" Foreground="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

            <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,180,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" ItemsSource="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" Template="{x:Null}">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Border Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="1" Width="476">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Border Height="110" Width="110" Margin="5,0,0,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                            <StackPanel Height="110" Width="110" Background="White">
                                                <Image Source="/NewExample;component/Images/Koala.jpg" Stretch="Fill"  Width="100" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageView}" Stretch="Fill"  Width="110" Height="110" Margin="0,-100,0,0"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleView}" Height="30"   Width="230" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Width="100" Foreground="Black" Margin="30,0,0,0" FontSize="18"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TypeViews}" Width="250" Foreground="Black" Margin="-360,30,0,0" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Medium" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextContent}" MaxHeight="84" Width="270" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" Margin="-450,50,0,0" FontWeight="Black" FontSize="19" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                                        <Image Source="{Binding TypeImageView}" Height="35" Width="35" Stretch="Fill" Margin="-120,10,0,0"/>
                                        <Image  Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding ClickButton}" Stretch="Fill" Margin="-60,10,0,0" Name="balloon_disclosure"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextView}" Width="250"  Foreground="Black" Margin="-360,100,0,0" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Medium" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

[image: Using Button]

Comment: What is the change? It's so minor that I can't really tell. I just tested your code and the text looks exactly the same to me, except that you set a `Width` on the `Button` which is too small, so some is cut off. The `FontSize`s and `FontStyle`s are the same.

Comment: This is just a sample. When i use this in my list box I can see lot's of differences. If you want to post my List box out put i will put it..

Comment: A picture won't help us to help you. A small working code example that demonstrates your problem will. Your current code example does not do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Get rid of the button's default padding, margin and styles etc, set its template to "{x:Null}"

```
<Button Height="200" Template="{x:Null}">
            <Button.Content>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Vijaya dhas" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Black"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Mobile App Developer Trainee" FontSize="26" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Chennai" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your reply. This helps me to solve my another problem. But Still now FontWeight is changing for all text blocks..

Comment: what do you mean by that? Are you after the look of the first or second screenshot?

Comment: Please verify my second screen shots. The third line 'Windows phone Developer', 'I phone Developer' Textblock is actually text weight id Semi Block. But after give it into Button content It becomes normal. Sorry for poor English..

Comment: There HAS to be another style definition either in the page or in your app.xaml which is overriding styles for textblocks placed in buttons. Create a brand new project and copy over the button xaml above to the default page without making any modifications, you will observe that the default style is displayed. Without knowing your custom styles defined in your page or xaml, it will be difficult to pinpoint what is exactly overriding the default style.

Comment: I have update question with my XAML. Please review that. I did not use any other style in this XAML.

Comment: weird, see my screenshot attached, I get a bold font as expected when i use your xaml. Do you have any style declarations in App.xaml?

Comment: No.. I did not define anything in App.xaml.. Anyway.. `Template="{x:Null}"` helps me lots.. Thanks for your answer and effort.. :) Thank you..!!